# GPU drivers seem installed but not being used

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gpu

I have a laptop with an NVIDIA MX150. I disabled secure boot and installed the nvidia-430 drivers and they are selected in "Additional drivers". However, nvidia-smi command is not found and system's info still show Intel HD Graphics. What did I miss?

Comment: Please open Nvidia X Server Settings and change to high performance profile in order to use the dGPU instead.

Comment: If I try to run nvidia settings it returns `ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system`

Comment: So, first check in UEFI settings and confirm Secure Boot is actually disabled. Also check whether or not the dGPU (Nvidia) is disabled, some systems allow selecting and/or disabling the dGPU from the firmware.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia you were right, secure boot was enabled again. Problem is that if I disable it, system will only run in low-graphics mode.

Comment: But the point is disabling it.

Comment: ye, there is a typo: if I disable it.

Comment: So,  there was/is a problem with  the Nvidia drivers. Now that  you have Secure Boot disabled please reinstall the drivers.

Comment: Ok, I disabled Secure Boot, uninstalled and reinstalled the drivers. Then, after rebooting, I still get the problem of low-graphics mode. I must enable Secure Boot to fix it.

Comment: You need to troubleshoot the drivers installation, not enable Secure Boot because that prevents the drivers from loading even if correctly installed. It seems you have other problems. Does the regular  system updates work?

Comment: Yes, I have no problem other than that. I'll look for a solution to it.